# NullPointerException while creating custom hardware profile (AVD)

Tags: command-line, nullpointerexception, android-virtual-device

I'm trying to create a custom hardware profile from the command line, but am receiving this error. I can do this in the AVD Manager, am I missing an option that is required to proceed?

```
C:\Users\tmcfarlin>android create avd -n my_android_21 -t 11 -b armeabi-v7a
Android 5.0.1 is a basic Android platform.
Do you wish to create a custom hardware profile [no]yes

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.promptForHardware(Main.java:1682)
    at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.createAvd(Main.java:1447)
    at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.doAction(Main.java:336)
    at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.run(Main.java:150)
    at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.main(Main.java:116)
```

Comment: Same here, Did you get any solution?